# Greasemonkey script is running on every web site

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I set a greasemonkey script to be included on only one web site:

```
http://example.com/*
```

but it's running on every web site I go too.. 
I removed it and added it again with only 1 include but it's still running on every page, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us the full header of the script.

Comment: Ah - I set the Include in the Greasemonkey options, but the meta include was *   - is working for only selected site now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually caused by a malformed metadata block.

There must be no leading space and directives are (usually) case-sensitive.

**Good:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==
```

**Bad:**

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name     YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
    // @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
    // ==/UserScript==
```

**Bad:**

```
//==UserScript==
//@name     YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
//@include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
//==/UserScript==
```

**Bad:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @INCLUDE  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==
```

etc.

---

---

Also the script options can override what is in your metadata block.  Check them or just uninstall and reinstall the script.