# My Greasemonkey script runs on every site except the one I want it to?

Tags: greasemonkey

I'm trying to set up a script to run on *Quora*, but it's running on every other site instead.
I have the `@include` directive in the metadata block, and under script settings/include, it's set to `include *`, and I can't see any way to remove that.

[Here's](http://userscripts-mirror.org/topics/133790.html) a thread about the same issue I'm having, but there's no `@exclude` directive to remove (although I did try putting `@exclude *` before the `@include`, but that didn't fix anything). I also checked my formatting against the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250121/greasemonkey-script-is-running-on-every-web-site) and I don't see any typos.

Here's my metadata block.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Quora fixer
// @namespace   quora
// @include     https://www.quora.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @description prevents links from opening in a new tab
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==UserScript==
```

Answer (score 1):

First, see and follow [My very simple Greasemonkey script is not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083669/my-very-simple-greasemonkey-script-is-not-running).
If the script is running on every other page, and there are no Quora-specific `@excludes`, then the script most-likely *is* running on Quora -- just not doing what you expect.

Other issues or actions:

1. You are using `@grant none` and `@require`-ing jQuery.  This [leads to conflicts and javascript crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146445/jquery-in-greasemonkey-1-0-conflicts-with-websites-using-jquery) on sites like Quora.  Use `@grant GM_addStyle`.
2. If the *Script Settings* tab (not to be confused with the *User Settings* tab) shows differently than the actual script source, then either you are not looking at the same file Greasemonkey is, or Greasemonkey and/or Firefox has become corrupted/confused.  In that case:

   1. Uninstall the Greasemonkey script.
   2. Completely clear the browser cache.
   3. Shutdown Firefox completely. Use *Task Manager*, or equivalent, to verify that there is no Firefox thread/task/process in memory.
   4. Go to your [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox).
   5. Enter the `gm_scripts` folder therein.
   6. If there are any subfolders left over from the script you just uninstalled, delete them.  In your case, the folders should have names similar to `Quora_fixer`.
   7. Restart Firefox.
   8. Make sure the script is not listed.
   9. Install the Greasemonkey script afresh.
   10. If it still doesn't work, create a new Firefox profile or try a different computer altogether.
3. Once the script fires on Quora and no relevant errors show on Firefox's *Browser Console* (see the first link above), then if the script still does not do what you expect, you may need to apply [AJAX-aware techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281441/fire-greasemonkey-script-on-ajax-request).